# Get richtext from a richedit in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, richedit

Is there a way to get the RTF data from a richedit without using savetostream as in

```
strStream := TStringStream.Create('') ;
try
  RichEdit.Lines.SaveToStream(strStream);
  Text := strStream.DataString;
  strStream.CleanupInstance;
finally
  strStream.Free
```

Comment: Do not call `CleanupInstance` explicitly, it is called while the stream is being destroyed.

Comment: In other words, use `Free()` instead of `CleanupInstance()`.  And you should use a `try/finally` in case `SaveToStream()` raises an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tim the only way to get the RTF data from an RichEdit control is using a Stream because the windows message ([`EM_STREAMOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774304%28VS.85%29.aspx)) wich retrieve the RTF Data require a [`EditStreamCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774368%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure, this is the way used by windows to transfer rtf data into or out of a richedit control.

So you can use your own sample code, or implement the call to the windows message [`EM_STREAMOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774304%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The SaveToStream() method uses `EM_STREAMOUT` internally.  Why not use `SaveToStream()`?

Answer (score 3):

```
function RichTextToStr(red : TRichEdit) : string;

var   ss : TStringStream;

begin
  ss := TStringStream.Create('');

  try
    red.Lines.SaveToStream(ss);
    Result := ss.DataString;
  finally
    ss.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure CopyRTF(redFrom,redTo : TRichEdit);

var   s : TMemoryStream;

begin
  s := TMemoryStream.Create;

  try
    redFrom.Lines.SaveToStream(s);
    s.Position := 0;
    redTo.Lines.LoadFromStream(s);
  finally
    s.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I can attest deviation from the pattern results in frustration....